# Rails 3 + SimpleModal + AJAX: submit button works only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, simplemodal

I have an Rails 3 AJAX form in a [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) dialog box that adds a row to a table each time it's submitted. I'm using the unobtrusive jquery-ujs approach. So far:

- The AJAX form works any number of times if it's not in a dialog box.
- It works exactly once if it's in a SimpleModal dialog box. After that the submit button stops working. No submit, no errors, no nothing, although it works fine when submitted manually from the js console, i.e. $('...').submit();

Feels like an event handler is dropped when SimpleModal moves the html to a dialog box, but everything in the [jquery-ujs source](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) looks like a .delegate() method, so I don't know why it wouldn't get reattached.

I suspect there's a very simple solution, something I'm just not aware of that solves the problem in about twenty characters.

Here's the relevant code:

Page js (app/assets/javascripts/binders.js):

```js
$(function() {

  // Hide the form initially:
  $('#add_binder_modal').hide();

  // Show as SimpleModal when add link clicked:
  $('#add_binder_link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#add_binder_modal').modal();
  });

  // Close on success:
  $("form").bind("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, status){
    $.modal.close();
  });
});
```

Here's my Rails form (app/views/binders/_form.js):

```js
#add_binder_modal.container
  = form_for Binder.new, :remote=>true do |f| 
    = f.text_field :subject
    = f.submit
```

I don't think you'll need it, but just in case, here's the controller (app/controllers/binders_controller.rb):

```ruby
class BindersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js 

  def create
    @binder = Binder.new(params[:binder])
    @binder.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to binders_path } 
      format.js
    end 
  end 

end
```

And finally the js that it responds with (app/views/binders/create.js.erb):

```haml
$('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'show', :locals=>{:binder=>@binder}))%>')
  .appendTo('.binders .atable tbody').hide().fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to dig into the simplemodal javascript source a bit. There was no magic bullet. It was just a matter of debugging and tracing what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick stab at a possibility (without more thoroughly understanding what you're doing): consider whether you need to use a .live(...) method instead of just .click(...). Or rather, the .on() or .delegate() depending on what version of jQuery you are using.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Thanks. I know it's kind of an obscure question. Not sure that'll do it though. The 'click' event is on the link that opens up the dialog box, so it's not going anywhere. It's the button IN the dialog box that get shifted around and fails to execute.